# Custom AlertView - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, background, uialertview, alert

I have an application in with shows alert views but i would like to customize the alert view so that i can attach an image to it. This is similar to how Temple Run shows its alert views. I have tried adding a background color but it dosent make the alert view itself the color.
Please Help!

Comment: You may consider writing your own, or using one of the many third-party flavours such as this one: https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets

Comment: pretty good tutorial for any one who comes here http://iosdevtricks.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/creating-custom-alert-view-for-iphone.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add images to the alert view, you can add an image view as a subview. To expand the alert view, set the message to be text containing some \n's

You can't change the colour of the alert.

Answer (score 0):

in IOS 7 or higher, use code

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 282)];
UIImage *wonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iberrys.png"];
imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
[imageView setImage:wonImage];
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Arirang List"
                                                     message:@"phiên bản: 1.0\n website: www.iberrys.com\n email: quangminh@berrys.com\nmobile: 0918 956 456"
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Đồng ý"
                                           otherButtonTitles: nil];
//check if os version is 7 or above
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    [alertView setValue:imageView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
}else{
    [alertView addSubview:imageView];
}
 [alertView show];
```

Answer (score -1):

Custom image Alertbox to replace Apple default blue alertBox
  [Here is the screenshot 1][1]  
  [here is the screenshot 2][2]: www.8land.org/download/s1.png

Some of usages
  # acting just like apple default alert but with your own image. look nicer and not scary to your users. 
  # create your own custom background images with any size, anywhere on screen. fadeOut animation effect was also added. 
  #. prompt users rate your app.
  #. acting like in-app purchase.
  #. use it as advertising, prompt users to download another of your app or somebody else.
  #. Get feedback from users.
  #. Buy coin or any virtual stuffs you offered.
  #. if you make your image like a banner, it will acts like a banner.
#. It can be acted just like popoverViewController in iPad. you might need to modify the code a little bit though.

get the code from github, it's open source under MIT.
  https://github.com/ajaxgeek/Alertbox

Dowload it and try it and give me your thought. possibility to improve this piece of snippet?

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the question. Try posting snippets of code instead of recommending a product (unless a recommendation is indeed suitable as an answer)